# Android Webview URL Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, webview

I am working on a project to authenticate to a website via a `WebView` in an android app. I have researched the issue quite a bit, the consensus is to use the `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` Method. However if I use a command such as `webview.loadUrl("https://github.com/login");` I never get debug message in the Catlog either when the page loads or when I login. Is there a reason why the `AuthRequest` would never come through?

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
    handler.proceed("me@test.com", "mypassword");
    Log.d("request","received")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of authentication.  onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() is called when an HTTP authentication request comes in (Basic/Digest authentication).  The example that you gave for when you go to https://github.com/login this is not a page that uses this type of authentication.

When the browser sees this type of authentication request it typically displays a login dialog box prompting the user for a username and password.

[more details on types of authentication](https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication)