# Android WebView - JWT Authentication

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview, jwt

I have an Android app that I'm switching from basic auth to JWT so that, among other reasons, I don't have to store the user's password locally. This is working well for all of my API requests, but one part of my app uses a `WebView` to show custom content that is hosted on my server. This content also requires authentication and currently I use the username/password combo in the `WebViewClient` class to supply the credentials. Now that I'm going to JWT I no longer have these credentials, only the token. Is there a way to supply alternative authentication to the `WebViewClient`? My code is Kotlin but the same principle applies in Java.

```
inner class WVClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view: WebView, handler: HttpAuthHandler, host: String, realm: String) {
        // WHAT DO I DO HERE INSTEAD?
        handler.proceed(username, password)
    }
}
```

Comment: `onReceivedHttpAuthRequest` fires only for Basic or Digest authentication [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39607182/9195194). With JWT, you'll have to determine when the page requires authorization yourself. How is the server expecting to receive the token? It's not a great idea to pass on the querystring, so you'd add it as a header, so you can try adding it in your own `WebViewClient`'s [`shouldInterceptRequest`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)).

Answer (score -1):

Per [dewey's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9195194/dewey) comment on my question, I looked into adding the auth header to the request rather than waiting for the site to present the auth request. Instead of relying on the WebViewClient's method to intercept the request, I'm simply adding the header in the "additional HTTP headers" optional argument when doing the initial load of the URL.

```
webView.loadUrl("https://...", mapOf("Authorization" to jwtToken))
```

Comment: can you clarify the mapOf("Authorization" to jwtToken) syntax ? Searching in Google only shows this example which you have written. Thanks.

Comment: @Nexus7_2012 it is Kotlin syntax, not Java. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-of.html